# Excel Document and login

Tags: excel, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a excel file with 2 columns username and password. I want to have a website with login.The code should auth the user name and password available in excel file for entering into website and if its not available it wont login.

If there are any examples please send me.

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to try a search for "asp classic website authentication"  or the like.  Authentication via a spreadsheet doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it really sounds not like a good idea but you asked for it:

use the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB Driver to acces the excel sheet like so:

```
dim conn : set conn = server.createObject("ADODB.Connection")
dim rs : set rs = server.createObject("adodb.recordset")
dim sql

conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" &_
          "myExcelFile.xls;" &_
          "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"""

sql = "SELECT * FROM myUsers where username = 'foo' and password = 'bar'"
rs.open sql, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
```

the possible connectionstrings for excel are listed [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel)

Comment: Hi I know it's not such a good idea but what can you do - I already have what you have pasted on top....how do I implement this on a login page considering I might have 20 users? and more to be added?

Comment: it is all there isn't it? the sql filters the user by name and password so you get back one is username and password exist

Comment: true but you see i might have 20-30 users with different user name and password i need something that is gonna loop through the excel columns look for each client's user name and password and if that exist let them to see their own row.

Comment: man you write that that the excel sheet has two columns. so why loop through columns? the sql statement gives you the user by his name and password. perhaps you should read something about sql first?

Comment: what am I missing here : strSQL = "SELECT *  FROM A1:c10000 where AccessID= "& Request.Form("txtPwd") &" Phone=" & Request.Form("phone")

Comment: yes see the sql variable in my code example. this one you have to edit with your strSQL. so it looks like: "... from [Users$]..." where Users$ is the name of the sheet.